# Is it permitted for a submission to terminate merely with probability 1?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

The question is in the title. I'm interested in submissions that terminate with probability 1 but have unbounded worst case running times.

This is related to the question [Do programs have to terminate?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/do-programs-have-to-terminate), but that question is specifically about submissions that definitely do not terminate.

For example, the challenge is "sort the array". Should an implementation of a randomized bogosort (shuffle the elements and see if the result is sorted) be permitted?

Comment: See also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12498

Comment: As [pointed out in a comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/converting-integers-to-english-words?noredirect=1&lq=1), those solutions actually may not terminate in real implementation, because of PRNG properties.

Comment: @user202729 Could you link to the actual comment?

Comment: @mbomb007 Oops, wrong link. [The comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/is-it-permitted-for-a-submission-to-terminate-merely-with-probability-1?noredirect=1#comment60659_17124).

Comment: If someone is persuaded by my comment, maybe they should write up an answer on that basis. But I don't think that this is a problem, as long as an ideal version of the algorithm works for all inputs - after all, because of minor implementation-specific details like "having a limit on memory used", most solutions by brute force don't work for large inputs, and consensus is fine with that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Yes

Banning submissions that work with a probability of 1 removes the option of rejection sampling which is an approach that already has been used countless times.

Comment: I think the main argument in favour of _yes_ is that the probability that the program runs forever is 0

Comment: @LuisMendo That is just rephrasing the question.

Comment: And yet it is a much more solid argument than just saying "it has already been used countless times"

Comment: Every computer program has probability 1 it terminate (but possible without return the result)

Comment: @RosLuP No, not at all. Following program's probability to terminate is 0.5: (pseudocode) `if( rand() > 0.5 ){ while(true){ print("something"); } }`

Comment: The question asker can require a guaranteed termination if they want to though, right?

Answer (score -6):

## No

If there is the possibility that a program does not terminate, then it does not actually solve the task. If a program does not do what it is supposed to do, it is not valid as an answer.

Comment: Just in general, for a discussion try to only post the side of the argument you agree with. Letting someone who disagrees make the other post will (hopefully) encourage discussion, rather than just a vote.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Everyone is encouraged to post their own opinions. I saw arguments for both so posted both, also with the thought that it might prevent a FGITW effect.

Comment: You can see some more discussion about it [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/a-proposal-to-combat-meta-bloat-the-big-consensus-freeze/11944#comment39869_11944) (I've linked to a comment specifically talking about why this wasn't thought to be a great idea). But basically this tends to actually cause a greater FGITW since people will tend not to look for future posts. This isn't a policy or anything, you can do what you want, but personally I think it makes these polls worse.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't think this is the case - and I hope I did not have any bias as I was undecided how to vote - so I thought it was best to present both arguments that were important to me.

Comment: This argument doesn't make sense as written because if a program terminates with probability 1 (as opposed to probability 0.99) then there is no possibility that it does not terminate.

Comment: On the other hand, in bogosort-like examples, some algorithms actually might never terminate for sufficiently large inputs, because the PRNG isn't capable of producing the specific random sequence that gives a correct answer. For a specific example, on a TI-83 calculator the PRNG only has about 4.6x10^18 possible states, so it's very likely that `randIntNoReps(1,25` is not actually capable of producing the output `{1,2,3,...,25}` no matter how many times you try.